# AttributeError in python code with socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm having an AttributeError that says "AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'upper'". I'm pretty sure I created and established the connection properly, and am still unsure what to do after consulting the socket documentation.

Thank you.

```py
import socket
from _thread import *
import threading

print_lock = threading.Lock()
list_of_clients = [] 

def threaded(data, addr, s):
  s.sendto(data.upper(), addr)
  while True:
    message = s.recv(1024)
    if not message:
      print('Bye')
      print_lock.release()
      break
    message = message.upper()
    print("Sending message to " + addr[0])
    s.sendto(message, addr)
  data.close()

def Main():

  list_of_clients = []
  serverName = 'localhost'
  serverPort = 12000

  with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM) as serverSocket:
    serverSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))
    while True :
      print('Ready to ping...')
      data, addr = serverSocket.accept()
      print(type(data))
      print_lock.acquire()
      print("Client connected ip:<" + str(addr) + ">")

      start_new_thread(threaded, (data, addr, serverSocket))
      print("Continue")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  Main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
s.sendto(data.upper(), addr)
```

`data` is defined here:

```
data, addr = serverSocket.accept()
```

The `accept` method returns a 2-tuple, [where the first element is a *socket object*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept) capable of sending and receiving data.

Therefore, instead of passing `serverSocket` to `threaded`, you should pass the first element of the `2-tuple`, *as well as whatever data you want to send*.